# Doctrine: Associative entity loaded on one to one relationship when not implicitly called

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

Why when I do not specifically call join in the entity repository does the associative entity get joined? I have checked how many queries are executing and the response is one. So I'm just wondering how doctrine is getting the data? I've tried using both "lazy" and "eager" loading and in both cases the associative entity is returned in the address object even though the query does not join it.

Please see below for: entities, entity repository, results and query count.

Entities:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class User
{
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string")
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="Address", inversedBy="user")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="address_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * @ORM\Id
 */
protected $address;
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class Address
{
 /**
  * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
  * @ORM\Id
  */
 private $id

/**
 * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="address", cascade={"all"}, fetch="LAZY")
 */
private $user;
}
```

Entity Repository:

```
class AddressRepository extends EntityRepository
{
    /**
     * @param $id
     * @param array $with
     * @return array
     */
    public function fetchById($id, array $with = [])
    {
        $select = ['a'];
        foreach($with as $row){
            switch($row){
                case User::class:
                    $select[] = 'u';
                    break;
            }
        }

        $query = $this->createQueryBuilder('a')->select($select);

        foreach($with as $row){
            switch($row){
                case User::class:
                    $query->leftJoin('a.user', 'u');
                    break;
            }
        }

        return $query->where('a.id = :id')->setParameter('id', $id)->getQuery()->getOneOrNullResult();
    }
}
```

Result:

```
//Called: $address->fetchById(5,[]);
object(stdClass)#757 (18) {
  ["__CLASS__"]=>
  string(23) "AppBundle\Entity\Address"
  ["id"]=>
  int(5)
  ["user"]=>
  object(stdClass)#793 (10) {
    ["__CLASS__"]=>
    string(27) "AppBundle\Entity\User",
    ["name"]=>
    string(4) "test"
    ["address"]=>
    string(23) "AppBundle\Entity\Address"
  }
}
```

Query Count:

```
array(1) {
  [1]=>
  array(4) {
    ["sql"]=>
    string(414) "SELECT a0_.id AS id_0 FROM address a0_ WHERE a0_.id = ?"
    ["params"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(1) "5"
    }
    ["types"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      int(2)
    }
    ["executionMS"]=>
    float(0.0001671314239502)
  }
}
```

Comment: doctrine only executes a new query when it is needed. And that is when you retrieve address data.

Comment: So doctrine is caching the results some where?

Comment: No.  When you ask for user details it should execute new queries although i am not sure about this with oneToOne relations. Test something like $address->getUser()->getName();

Comment: I tried call $address->getUser()->getName(); but no additional query was called.